# How to write JUnit test cases to check range of values?

Tags: junit

I want to check whether the given input falls within the range of 1 to 100 (integer).

how to write **JUnit test case**  for this task?

Comment: Not sure why you are testing input values in a unit test, shouldn't your code validate the input and your unit test verify that the code is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Assert.assertTrue(value >= 1 && value <= 100);
```